# Upper bound for the sum of fourth powers

Tags: inequality

I want to prove the inequality for positive $a,b,c$
$$(a+b)^4+(a+c)^4+(b+c)^4\leq 2((a+c)^2(b+c)^2+(a+b)^2(b+c)^2+(a+c)^2(b+a)^2)$$
I found it very interesting, due to the fact that the opposite inequality holds with constant $1$ instead of $2$.
All my attempts to solve this fails. The main reason is due to the sign of this inequality.
One of my attemp was to show that
$(c+b)^4\leq (c+b)^2(a+c)^2+(c+b)^2(b+a)^2$

Unfortunately this ineqaulity does not hold.
I check the inequality is true numerically using $10^6$ iterations with random numbers $a,b,c$.
Could you please help me?

Comment: I think one of the $(a+c)^2(b+c)^2$ in your RHS should be $(a+b)^2(a+c)^2$.

Comment: $RHS-LHS=16abc(a+b+c)$. This ie essentially https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula in disguise.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Indeed. Thank you very much.